# Collection View Covering Previous Content View's Label - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a collection view which shows images. Underneath the image, there is a label saying what the photo is. My issue is that when the collection view makes it to the second line, the images on the second line cover the labels for the images on the top line. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

My code:

```
private func collectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cellWidthHeightConstant: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.2
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50,
                                           left: 10,
                                           bottom: 0,
                                           right: 10)
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidthHeightConstant, height: cellWidthHeightConstant)
        
        return layout
    }
```

```
fileprivate let bg: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return iv
    }()
    
    fileprivate let lbl: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    
    private enum Constants {
        static let imageHeight: CGFloat = 80.0
        static let verticalSpacing: CGFloat = 82.0
        static let horizontalPadding: CGFloat = 8.0
        static let profileDescriptionVerticalPadding: CGFloat = 8.0
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        contentView.addSubview(bg)
        contentView.addSubview(lbl)
        
        bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: Constants.imageHeight).isActive = true
        
        lbl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: Constants.horizontalPadding).isActive = true
        lbl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -Constants.horizontalPadding).isActive = true
        lbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bg.bottomAnchor, constant: Constants.profileDescriptionVerticalPadding).isActive = true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you are using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`,  make `the layout.itemSize.height` larger

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. I've updated my post with more code.

Comment: `layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidthHeightConstant, height: cellWidthHeightConstant * 1.6)`